# Is it okay to ask a question about story writing?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask a question about science-fiction short story writing, or is there a specific SE forum about writing tips?

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-writing-science-fiction-part-of-this-site?rq=1?

Comment: @Richard Yes; [it's off-topic according to Rob](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15/21267)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. You cannot ask questions about your writing. It's specifically contrary to our [stated site policies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

> *If your question is about...*
>
> *Writing science fiction, ask on [Writers - Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*

If you're looking for info about sci-fi concepts, you might want to try [Worldbuilding:SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: By this,  do you mean you can't ask questions about a story you've written? Because that's what it sounds like, though I can't find anything in the link about that (ignoring the fact it would be tacky)

Comment: Ah, no. It would be perfectly acceptable for an author to ask an on-topic question about their own works. It might border on spam but that's a different issue

Comment: Okay, makes more sense now.